# Why does this variadic argument count macro fail with VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I got the following implementation to get the number of arguments in a variadic macro (currently limited to 16 args). However, for VS2010 the output is always `1`, no matter how many arguments are passed. [With GCC](http://ideone.com/uUVUM), the output is correct, bringing me to the conclusion that I must have missed something specific for MSVC (10).

```
#define PP_NARGS(...) \
    _xPP_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

#define _xPP_NARGS_IMPL(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,N,...) N

int main(){
    int i = PP_NARGS(A,V,C,X,Y,Z);

    std::cout << i;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So, question is as the title states, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Does the following work-around help?

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define PP_NARGS(...) \
    EXPAND(_xPP_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0))
```

I think your macro isn't wrong in particular, but
MSVC's `__VA_ARGS__` expansion seems to behave differently from C99.

Comment: Omg, it *does* work! Awesome! Do you have an explanation why though?

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-)
Honestly, I can't explain why(Doh).
As I wrote in the answer, I think your macro is fine in C99 standard.
I interpret the `EXPAND` stuff as a purely work-around, and probably there
isn't any technically interesting matter in it...
According to
[here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement),
this seems like VC's bug-ish behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for this workaround. Works as described in VS14 CTP3 (where a bug, acknowledged by MS in 2008 [cf. Ise's link], is still present).

Comment: @IseWisteria @Xeo I was just hit with a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209120/invalid-argument-count-in-a-variadic-macro) upon my investigation, I realized that `__VA_ARGS__` are expanded *after* they are passed into the macro. In your case, `x1` becomes `A,V,C,X,Y,Z` as a whole. The `EXPAND` trick forces it to be expanded earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems that Visual Studio is expanding `__VA_ARGS__` *after* passing it into the subsequent macro, while gcc expands it before passing.

In your case, `PP_NARGS(A,V,C,X,Y,Z)` binds `A,V,C,X,Y,Z` to `__VA_ARGS__`, and then passes it as a whole to `_xPP_NARGS_IMPL`.

As a test, run:

```
#define PP_NARGS(...) \
    _xPP_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)

#define _xPP_NARGS_IMPL(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,N,...) \
  (std::cout << #x1 << std::endl, N) 

int main() {
  int i = PP_NARGS(A, V, C, X, Y, Z);
  std::cout << i;
  return 0;
}
```

You will see `A, V, C, X, Y, Z` printed on the screen, and not just `A` as you would probably expect.

---

A possible solution, as suggested by Ise Wisteria already, is to force the expansion via:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define PP_NARGS(...) \
    EXPAND(_xPP_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0))
```