# Invalid argument count in a variadic macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to create a macro that would iterate over a defined list of terms, and for each invoke another macro, possibly with additional argument list. Here is what I have got:

```
#define ITERATE_OVER_TERMS(MACRO, ...) \
MACRO(Term1, __VA_ARGS__) \
MACRO(Term2, __VA_ARGS__) \
MACRO(Term3, __VA_ARGS__) \
... and so on
```

However, when I was trying to use it with Visual Studio 2015, i get an error

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'BODY'
```

where `BODY` is the name of the macro passed as the `MACRO` argument. While technically a warning, it shows that something has gone wrong with the expansion.

In an attempt to narrow down the error, I reduced my example to the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ITERATE(MACRO, ...) \
MACRO(1, __VA_ARGS__) MACRO(2, __VA_ARGS__)

#define BODY(IterationArg, Arg1, Arg2) \
std::cout << IterationArg << Arg1 << Arg2 << std::endl;

int main() {
  ITERATE(BODY, 8, 9)
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the error as shown above, while I expected it to compile succesfully and produce the output

```
189
289
```

It does seem to compile with g++, but not Visual Studio.
What am I missing? Is there some walkaround for this to work?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 still has a partial support for C99 preprocessor. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: @KABoissonneault They seem to support variadic macros for a long time (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx) There are versions for VS2005 already.

Comment: They support variadic macros, but to be honest I've never seen a macro passed as a macro argument. Visual Studio probably expects you to evaluate `BODY` right inside the `main` body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Visual Studio expands `__VA_ARGS__` after they are being passed into a subsequent macro, and not before. This has caused problems in the past as well, for example here --
[Why does this variadic argument count macro fail with VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530505/why-does-this-variadic-argument-count-macro-fail-with-vc)

In your case, consider a simple change in the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define ITERATE(MACRO, ...) \
MACRO(1, __VA_ARGS__) MACRO(2, __VA_ARGS__)

#define BODY(IterationArg, Arg1, Arg2) \
std::cout << #Arg1 << std::endl;

int main() {
  ITERATE(BODY, 8, 9)
    return 0;
}
```

The argument `#Arg1` is stringified, showing us its contents in the output:

```
8, 9
8, 9
```

Not what we expected, huh?

A solution is the same as in the linked question: force an expansion through a dummy `EXPAND` macro:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x

#define ITERATE(MACRO, ...) \
EXPAND(MACRO(1, __VA_ARGS__)) EXPAND(MACRO(2, __VA_ARGS__))
```

This gives you the desired result both in VS and gcc.