# Preprocessor macro that call another one : MSVC issue?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to develop by myself a kind of for_each macro. I built it from scratch because I found other implementation in this website too much complicate and I do not find any resources on internet to learn tricks and tips about macros.

So, what I began to do is to make a make a macro that prints the square of a value. after I created a macro `MAP` that call `MAP_ONE` that calls `f` with the first arg.

On clang and gcc, this code works well :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SQUARE(x) std::cout << x * x << std::endl;

#define MAP(f, ...) MAP_ONE(f, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MAP_ONE(f, x, ...) f(x)

int main() {
  MAP(PRINT_SQUARE, 5, 8);
  return 0;
}
```

On MSVC it does not work. The errors are :

```
..\main.cpp(12): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list
..\main.cpp(12): error C2568: '<<': unable to resolve function overload
..\main.cpp(12): note: could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::endl(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &)'
```

Is it a MSVC bug or is it normal and I just did something forbiden?

Thanks to the answer of Afshin, I modified the prior code to :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define PRINT_SQUARE(x) std::cout << ((x) * (x)) << std::endl;

#define MAP(f, ...) MAP_ONE(f, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MAP_ONE(f, x, ...) f(x) f(__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
  MAP(PRINT_SQUARE, 5, 8);
  return 0;
}
```

On clang and GCC it prints : 25 and 64. On MSVC it does not compile :

```
D:\Desktop\Programmation\macro\main.cpp:12: error: C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

Comment: MSVC version???

Comment: MSVC verrsion 15.9.2

Comment: if you call `MAP_ONE` it works correctly. it is strange that with calling `MAP` it does not work.

Comment: It seems that for MSVC x is not equal to `5` but it is equal to `5, 8`, so it is evaluated to 8 * 8 = 64

Comment: @AntoineMorrier solved problem. check reply. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This solves the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define EXPAND(x) x

#define PRINT_SQUARE(x) std::cout << x * x << std::endl;

#define MAP_ONE(f, x, ...) f(x)

#define MAP(f, ...) EXPAND(MAP_ONE(f, __VA_ARGS__ ))

int main() {
  MAP(PRINT_SQUARE, 5, 8);
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209964/5529197) link. It seems there is problem with expanding `__VA_ARGS__` in VS and this trick will solve the problem.

Comment: It does not. It now compiles, but instead of printing 25, it prints 64...

Comment: @AntoineMorrier yea I noticed too.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I got this solution too. It seems that MSVC is too more compliant ahaha

Comment: You need to use `/experimental:preprocessor` to use the latest preprocessor module of msvc