# Variadic macro expansion's going wrong

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, c99, variadic-macros

Consider the following code

```
#define COMB(F, ...) F(__VA_ARGS__)


#define ADD(X, Y) (X + Y)


int foo() {
    return COMB(ADD, 1, 2);
}
```

I have done some experiments on Godbolt. Microsoft VS v19.22 (with /E flag) fails at preprocessing the macro's. It gives the following error

```
int foo() {

    return (1, 2 + );

}

example.cpp

<source>(8): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'ADD'
```

GCC (with -E flag) simply outputs as expected

```
int foo() {
    return (1 + 2);
}
```

I took a look at the C99 standard. But I am still not sure which compiler is doing it right?

I hope somebody can help me with clarifying this.

Comment: Does VC support variadic macros?

Comment: It does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/variadic-macros?view=vs-2019

Comment: "Microsoft VS fails" and "I took a look at the C99 standard" kind of sums up the problem. You shouldn't assume that VS 1) correctly follows C99 2) correctly follows any standard at all.

Comment: I am not assuming VS is doing anything right. That is why I have posted my question.

Comment: Well the code works as expected on every other compiler (I just tried gcc, clang, icc and msvc). Draw your conclusions from there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this variadic argument count macro fail with VC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530505/why-does-this-variadic-argument-count-macro-fail-with-vc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think gcc is correct. Although C11 6.10.3/12 describes the invocation of COMB as having two arguments (`ADD` and `1,2`), once `COMB` has been expanded the resulting token sequence is `ADD` `(` `1` `,` `2` `)`, and 6.10.3.4/1 is clear that the result of the first replacement is rescanned as a preprocessing token sequence. An argument from a previous step that consisted of multiple tokens is not somehow glued into a single token for rescanning.

6.10.3.4/1:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ##
>   processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. **The
>   resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned**, along with all subsequent
>   preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace

Comment: Interesting do you know if this interpretation/derivation differs in C99?

Comment: @ArisKoning I think (don't quote me on this) that the text hasn't changed from C99 to C11. I'd have to go get the diff draft. though.

Comment: @ArisKoning C99 added the part about "and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed". The stuff about placemarkers for ## is new in C99. What it means more precisely in practice, I don't know.

Comment: @ArisKoning But then again MCVC struggled with C90 compliance to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

MSVC expands `__VA_ARGS__` after passing it into the macro. You'll have to manually expand the macro like this:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define COMB(F, ...) EXPAND(F(__VA_ARGS__))

#define ADD(X, Y) (X + Y)
```

GCC is the correct compiler in this case.

Comment: Yup, this seems to be the workaround that I was searching for. VS does the rescan too soon, i.e. before the expansion of `__VA_ARGS__`.